# Actualizar valores de widget flotante

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola estoy realizando un widget flotante el cual me permite ver la velocidad de con que descargo o subo un archivo en internet, para ello consto de un servicio el cual me lanza mi widget flotante con 2 TextView, subida y descarga y necesito actualizar esos valores a continuación muestro el código. 
codigo:

```
public class NetworkService extends Service {


private WindowManager windowManager;
private View chatHead;
WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
private TextView up,down;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //Obtenemos la instancia de WindowsManager
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    //Instanciamos el objeto que queremos adjuntar a WindowsManager
    chatHead =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.servicio_flotante,null,false);

    //Aplicamos parametros que necesitemos
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    //WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
    //Posicion donde queremos que se acople
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    //TouchListener para mover el elemento por la pantalla
    chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX
                            + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY
                            + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    //Acoplamos el elemento a la pantalla
    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (chatHead != null)
        windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}}
```

En el R.layout.servicio_flotante lo que hay son 2 textView y quiero que este se me actualize recibiendo los valores de upSpeed y downSpeed de este fragmento de código

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo= connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
        int upSpeed = networkCapabilities.getLinkUpstreamBandwidthKbps();
        int downSpeed = networkCapabilities.getLinkDownstreamBandwidthKbps();

    }
```

No tengo idea de como actualizar esos valores